# Nesting ShapeRenderer.begin/end in SpriteBatch.begin/end

Tags: java, render, libgdx, shapes

Is it possible to draw shapes by using `ShapeRenderer` between `SpriteBatch` `begin` and `end` calls.

I have tried but no result, only SpriteBatch textures are drawn, no shape is on the scene. Sample code is as followed below :

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledCircle);
shapeRenderer.setColor(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f);
shapeRenderer.filledCircle( 100, 100, 100);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

I have a orthographic camera created by these commands :

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
camera.setToOrtho(true);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `ShapeRenderer` and `SpriteBatch` set state in OpenGL that they expect to remain constant during their use.  Nesting them can create problems.  See [this post in the badlogic forum](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6860&p=31916&hilit=spritebatch+shaperenderer#p31916).

This should probably be spelled out a bit more clearly in the docs.